# Logging to a text file inside the applications folder

Tags: c#

I'm using the following code to log the results of my application to a .txt file.

```
string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory.ToString() + "\\measurementslog.txt";
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
{
    sw.WriteLine(accumulatedLines);
}
```

The folder of the application is located on the desktop. The log is created inside the applications folder. If I end the logging process and restart it, it sometimes creates a separate measurementslog.txt file on the desktop (not in the applications folder).

Would anybody know, why this is happening?

Comment: use log4net....

Comment: ... or any logging system for that matter. log4net or NLog would both be good choices, but there are many more. They will take care of a lot of stuff you have to do on your own if logging like that. They are tested, stable and fairly easy to configure.

Comment: Why should anyone use log4net or any other logging library for writing text to a file? :) Of course these are great libraries and it's good to know about them but please don't use the 20kg hammer for a small nail.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási Because OP is talking about *logging* but is actually only writing to a text file. If he wants to log, I suggest using a logging system. If he wants to write to a text file - fine. But he explicitly said "log".

Comment: I'd suggest a logging library for complex application level logging scenarios indeed, but there might be difference between two "log" requirement. I just say that if it's a simple append to a hard-coded file then it's an overkill to introduce log4net for example. However it's definitely worth mentioning as I wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code to achieve your results.

```
var programDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
var path = Path.Combine(programDirectory, @"log.txt");
File.AppendAllText(path, accumulatedLines);
```

Take care though, that it works reliably only in *standalone* applications (console and desktop for instance). When you're for example in a Web application context or in a Unit test runner context, the `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` may return the assembly of the runner context which may be unexpected for the developer.

Note that the provided code is not tested, doesn't contain the appropriate checks, and meant only as a short demo snippet.

Answer (score 2):

There're **two** problems with `Environment.CurrentDirectory`:

1. It can be *changed*: `Environment.CurrentDirectory = @"C:\bla-bla-bla";` and thus *current directory* is not necessatily the path your program's started from
2. User not necessarily has *write permissions* for the catalog; e.g. `C:\Program Files` (typical place for the applications to install) usually *can't be written* unless user has *Power User* or *Admin* role.

I suggest using standard path for logs: `System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData`

Something like this:

```
  //TODO: Put a better name for the log file (not log.txt)
  // E.g. $"{Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name}.log.txt"
  // You may want to create a subfolder, say \Logs\ as well 
  File.AppendAllText(
    Path.Combine(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData, "log.txt"), 
    accumulatedLines);
```

Answer (score 0):

`CurrentDirectory` is not necessary executable directory,

Use this if you want it to be near executable

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
```

Answer (score 0):

Does anything in your app change the working directory?  Instead of using Environment.CurrentDirectory each time.  I would recommend having a readonly field ("StartFolder"), which on app start you initialise with Environment.CurrentDirectory.  That way, if anything does cause the working directory to change, you still have the full path of the application directory.